Is there a superfluid dual to superinsulators?
It's well known that there are many analogies between Superconductors and Superfluids. The diagram below explains a few:
$$ \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superconductors}} \\ \text{0 electrical resistance}  \\ \text{expels magnetic fields/flux pinning} \end{matrix} \leftrightarrow  \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superfluids}} \\  \text{0 viscosity } \\ \text{expels angular momentum/rotational vortices}  \end{matrix}$$
We also have a similar such diagram that can be drawn between Superconductors and Superinsulators, a closely related state of matter .
$$ \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superconductors}} \\ \text{0 electrical resistance}  \\ \text{expels magnetic fields/flux pinning} \end{matrix} \leftrightarrow  \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superinsulators}} \\  \text{Infinite electrical resistance } \\ \text{expels electric fields/ electric flux pinning}  \end{matrix}$$
I am curious how far these analogies can be stretched. Does there exist then a closely related dual state to superfluidity where viscosity is 100% analogoes to the superinsulating dual of superconductivity? I.E. can the following diagram be filled with another phase of matter for the ??? to make it commute:
$$ \begin{matrix} \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superconductors}} \\ \text{0 electrical resistance}  \\ \text{expels magnetic fields/flux pinning} \end{matrix}   & \leftrightarrow & \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superfluids}} \\  \text{0 viscosity } \\ \text{expels angular momentum/rotational vortices}  \end{matrix} \\ \updownarrow & & \updownarrow  \\  \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{Superinsulators}} \\  \text{Infinite electrical resistance } \\ \text{expels electric fields/ electric flux pinning}  \end{matrix} & \leftrightarrow  & \begin{matrix} \bf{\text{???}} \\  \text{Infinite viscosity } \\ \text{expels ????}  \end{matrix} \end{matrix} $$
I am extremely curious what that ??? state of matter should be.
